# Method works during a debug session, but not in production

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, microsoft-graph-api, windows-server

I am writing an app that uses Microsoft Identity as an external login provider. The bearer token is being saved for use with the following method.

```
public async Task<string> GetMicrosoftGraphPhotoAsync(string token)
    {
        var clientId = _configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").GetSection("ClientId").Value;
        var vaultUrl = _configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").GetSection("KeyVaultUrl").Value;
        var certName = _configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").GetSection("KeyVaultCertificateName").Value;
        var creds = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        var client = new CertificateClient(vaultUri: new Uri(vaultUrl), credential: new DefaultAzureCredential());
        var cert = await client.DownloadCertificateAsync(certName);

        var tenantId = _configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").GetSection("TenantId").Value;
        var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .WithCertificate(cert.Value)
            .Build();

        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var authProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) =>
        {
            var assertion = new UserAssertion(token);
            var result = await cca.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, assertion).ExecuteAsync();

            request.Headers.Authorization =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
        });

        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
        var stream = await graphClient.Me.Photos["120x120"]
            .Content
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();

        if (stream == null)
        {
            return null!;
        }

        //create image from stream
        var image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(stream, out var format);
        return image.ToBase64String(format);
    }
}
```

The method is able to pull an image from graph in my local environment, but when I upload the code to a Windows Server 2019 box running IIS 10, I get the following error:

Error loading external login information (Graph). System.InvalidOperationException: Bearer token authentication is not permitted for non TLS protected (https) endpoints. at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted(ValueTask task) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RedirectPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted(ValueTask task) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RedirectPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted(ValueTask task) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipeline.Send(HttpMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipeline.SendRequest(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Security.KeyVault.KeyVaultPipeline.SendRequest(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Security.KeyVault.KeyVaultPipeline.SendRequest[TResult](RequestMethod method, Func`1 resultFactory, CancellationToken cancellationToken, String[] path) at Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates.CertificateClient.GetCertificate(String certificateName, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at OfficialBlogProject.Helpers.Helper.GetCertificateAsync(CertificateClient certificateClient, SecretClient secretClient, String certificateName) at OfficialBlogProject.Helpers.Helper.LoadCertificate(IConfiguration config, String certificateName) at OfficialBlogProject.Services.BasicExternalLoginService.GetMicrosoftGraphPhotoAsync(String token) at OfficialBlogProject.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.ExternalLoginModel.OnGetCallbackAsync(String returnUrl, String remoteError).

I tried enabling TLS for IIS, but this did not solve the problem. Is there something different I should be doing in the production environment? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any chance your `vaultUrl` is using http instead of https? Also, looks like your `certName` and `vaultUrl` are getting the same config values, is this intentional?

Comment: Hi Michael, this was a typo on my part. I checked the vaultUrl and it is using https.

Comment: I noticed that you used `new DefaultAzureCredential()` in your code to get authoration to get secrets stored in azure key vault. I want to confirm that if you get the `cert` correctly after it deployed to `Windows Server 2019 IIS 10`?

Comment: You can also try the action in my post below if you are not sure about it. Pls let me know if it doesn't help and I'll delete it.

Comment: The error stack indicates that the certificate download from KV failed. @Michael, what versions of `Azure.Identity` and `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates` are you using? The only think I can think of is that RedirectPolicy kicked in after you got 30x status code from KV and you were redirected to non https url. 
Can you capture the traffic in your VM to see if there is an outgoing request to your KV url?

Comment: I managed to easily repro the same stack trace by using non http KV path. Any chance your dev environment is using `appsettings.Development.json` and your VM is using `appsettings.json`? And that they have different configuration values?

Comment: Michael, Tiny, and everyone else, thank you for your help with this issue, the culprit was appsettings. I tried encrypting appsettings as suggested by another developer to make the file more secure. The file was decrypting correctly on my computer, but the code had to be changed so malformed values wouldn't be produced on the vm. Once this change was made, I was able to pull the picture from graph.

Answer (score 1):

This is an assumption.

In my humble opinion, using `new DefaultAzureCredential()` means the environment should have been done some configuration for the authentication. For example when we use visual studio to run a program, and if the user used to sign in VS has the permission to access target azure key vault, then then authentication will be passed.

[image]

But when publish the application to production environment, if we didn't configure anything else, authentication won't be passed. If this is the reason for the issue, then we may try to create an azure ad application and give this application the permission to access the target azure key vault, then set [Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme#environment-variables) in the windows server to offer the authentication. Variables should be `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`, `AZURE_TENANT_ID` and `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`.